# Example of a continuous martingale being non-square-integrable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Is there any example of a continuous martingale $M$ such that $M_0 = 0$ and it is not square integrable?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X(t)=X$ where $X\in L^1\setminus L^2$.

Comment: If $\mathcal{F}_0$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, the process in your example is not a martingale.

Comment: @YuxuanLiu Ok??

Comment: Thanks! But in my context the martingale is assumed to have constant as its initial value(or say the initial filtration is trivial), sorry for not clarifying this. In such case, is there any example of being continuous but not globally square integrable?